# Ubuntu Wi-Fi Not Working on Lenovo Laptop?

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04

I just performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 from a live CD. The only problem I've been having is that I cannot connect to any wireless network. The wireless network I'm trying to connect to appears in the list but when I attempt to connect to it, it takes a long time and then says "Disconnected - you are now offline". Unfortunately, my laptop (Lenovo Z51) doesn't have an ethernet port I can use to connect to the router directly so I'm copying the output of commands via USB. I also know that the problem is not with my router or with the network credentials since I can connect with no problems using other devices with the same credentials. I previously had Fedora and the network was working. Anyways, here is some information that may be helpful.

Here is the output of the command lshw -C network:

```
sj005@SJ-PC:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 15
       serial: f0:76:1c:ae:fb:45
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1204000-d1204fff memory:d1200000-d1203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 93
       serial: 34:e6:ad:c1:d3:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=25.15.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:53 memory:d1100000-d1101fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I also ran the wireless script found here: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
and pasted the results to pastebin. Here is the link:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12816824/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried with propietery driver in `software & updates`. Im using Lenovo laptop G40.

Comment: I checked the Lenovo website. It doesn't seem they have an Ubuntu driver for my network card. Could updating my kernel solve the issue? My current version is 3.19.0-15

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem paste this command into the terminal

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
```

Reboot and see if that helps.

Comment: Didn't work on Lenovo Yoga 920.

Answer (score 0):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help. The solution that finally worked for me was simply a system update. I used a USB network card to do a full system and kernel update. After rebooting, I can connect to the network. Anyways, I appreciate all your suggestions.